# Changing WordPress url to search friendly

Tags: wordpress, url, url-routing, custom-wordpress-pages

I do have a wordpress website where I do have a filter section (Not Search Section) which accepts multiple parameter. Currently wordpress searches it generating a url like mysite.com/?data1=abc&data2=def&data3=ghi .
I want to change the url to be looking like mysite.com/data1/abc/data2/def/data3/ghi/ , Which is more Search friendly.

Answer (score 0):

you should need to add below code in your theme `function.php` file to change Wordpress default search redirection

```
function Wordpress_Change_Url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'Wordpress_Change_Url' );
```

Above its just idea so you can add all variables in this

Comment: Hello, I just tried running it, but it perfectly works on the search but what about something like filter. Just as I have a job portal site and I need to filter jobs, and I want to show url in managed way. I could not figure out that

Comment: Also, after redirection its showing page 404 not found. I want to let the content remain same but just the url different